# SpringBoot DataJPA - How to add new datasource objects and configure the entitymanager, transaction manager at runtime

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, multi-tenant

In my multitenancy application, I currently have a spring configuration class containing DataSourceMap which contains the tenants' datasource objects with their tenantId.

At the time of app deployment the tenant db user credentials are fetched and datasource objects are stored in the DataSourceMap. Based on the tenant identifier from each http request the correct datasource is found and used to perform DB operations.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    public DataSourceMap dataSourceMap = new DataSourceMap();
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public DataSourceMap dataSourceMap(){
        // for loop of the credentials for creating the datasource objects
        // put the datasource objects in the map 
        this.dataSourceMap.setDataSources(tenantIdentifier, dataSource);
        return this.dataSourceMap;
    }
}


@Component
public class TenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        // logic to select the current tenant
    }
}


@Component
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {
    @Autowired
    private transient DataSourceMap dataSourceMap;

    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        // logic to find the datasource object from the datasource map
        // return the connection from this datasource
    }

    //... other required methods

}

@Configuration
public class MultiTenancyConfig {
    

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Autowired MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl multiTenantConnectionProvider,
            @Autowired TenantIdentifierResolverImpl currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.identity");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY, CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.class);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, false);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Currently I am able to use the datasource objects and perform DB operations as expected.
I am able to get the correct datasource object per request, but all these datasource objects are created at the application deployement.

Created new users in DB using a different service and got the credentials to create new datasource objects.

I want to add new datasource objects with the credentials and put them in DataSourceMap.
**How can I achieve that ?**

**If there is any better way of handling dynamic datasource objects please recommend.**